# ido mode not previewing buffers names on switch buffer C-x b

Tags: ido

I just started using `ido-mode` and can't seem to get it to give a buffer list on switch-buffer. It works fine for visit file (`C-x` `C-f`) and kill buffer (`C-x` `k`), but not on `C-x` `b`, which is a much more common event. I've just updated to Emacs 24.4.1 (i686-pc-mingw32), but that didn't solve the problem.

Comment: How are you activating it?

Comment: To what function is `C-x b` bound? (Do `C-h k C-x b`)

Comment: I am activating ido by typing M-x ido-mode.  C-x b is bound to s-switch-to-buffer. Ah, now I see the problem. s-switch-to-buffer has been in my .emacs for longer than I can remember. I removed this and now it works. Thanks.

Comment: @Llaves: please submit an answer and accept it so that other users will know that the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my .emacs file remapped C-x b to a function called s-switch-to-buffer, which probably got added back in the lisp machine days and I had completely forgotten it was there. Once I removed that, everything behaved as expected. Thanks to Dan for prompting to look at the key-binding.

Answer (score 4):

To activate ido mode, put this in your init file:

```
;; make buffer switch command auto suggestions, also for find-file command
(ido-mode 1)
```

Then, `C-x b` will call the ido version of switch buffer function, and you can press tab key for completion

Putting this in your init file, may be interesting:

```
;; make ido display choices vertically
(setq ido-separator "\n")

;; display any item that contains the chars you typed
(setq ido-enable-flex-matching t)
```

**EDIT:**

With the setup above, everything should work as expected. If the `TAB` key is not working as expected, try with the `SPC` key to check. Not sure, but you may have a minor mode active with a keymap overriding some keybinding of ido.

Comment: that's not it. You will note in my original question that ido is working for other functions, just not for switch buffers. Thus, I do have the mode enabled.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that `C-x b` is bound to `ido-switch-buffer`, not to something else. You can check what it is currently bound to by running `M-x describe-key <RET> C-x b`.